# javascript prevent functions from being executed in quick succession

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have problems when certain functions in my code are executed in quick succession. I thought maybe a few lines of javascript would prevent trigger-happy folks.

So here's what I hoped to use.

```
   function change(){
   if(mod == 1 || mod == null){
   var mod=2;
   //function goes here    
   window.setTimeout(function(){var mod=1;}, 500);
   }
```

Is there a way to do this that actually works?

I also feel there should be a more global approach to this I'm not thinking of.

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually trying to do... but as per your title it sounds like you're looking for "callbacks"

Comment: essentially disable the function until a period of time has passed...

Comment: If you store the handle of the timeout and then call `window.clearTimeout(handle)`, I think that will give you the behavior you're looking for since the timeout be reset on each successive call.

Comment: Ah. That seems much more streamlined than what I was doing.

Comment: I'm assuming you're checking against the `mod` variable and using a setTimeout to reset it? If so you only need to remove the `var` from the inner function used in the setTimeout. It's creating another variable called `mod` that has nothing to do with the outer `mod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throttle or debounce the callback. There's a nice (jQuery-optional) library that wraps all this up for you: [jQuery throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

> jQuery throttle / debounce allows you to rate-limit your functions in multiple useful ways. Passing a delay and callback to `$.throttle` returns a new function that will execute no more than once every `delay` milliseconds. Passing a delay and callback to `$.debounce` returns a new function that will execute only once, coalescing multiple sequential calls into a single execution at either the very beginning or end.

Since you just commented that you want to

> disable the function until a period of time has passed

it sounds like you're looking for the *debounce* use-case.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for... The debounce code seems to be an embellished elapsed-time function though. Not sure I can't use something better on a much smaller scale, but it's certainly worth it globally.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution almost works. Your problem is you're not creating a closure for `mod` but instead create another variable called `mod` in the setTimeout. This should work:

```
   function change(){
     if(mod == 1 || mod == null){
       var mod=2;
       //function goes here    
       window.setTimeout(function(){mod=1;}, 500);
     }
   }
```